# ¿Por qué no se alternan los cuadros blancos y negros con Java JSTL EL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Tengo que representar un tablero de ajedrez utilizando la tecnología EL JSTL de Java. quiero hacer que cuando la fila y la columna suman impar me ponga el fondo negro y cuando es par me lo ponga blanco. Con el código que pongo a continuación me salen todos los cuadros negros y no entiendo el por qué.
Gracias de antemano.

```
    <%@ taglib prefix= "v" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tablero ajedrez</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:300px; height:300px; border: 1px solid red;">
        <v:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="8" step="1">
            <tr style="border: 1px solid red;"><v:forEach var="j" begin="1" end="8" step="1">
                <v:choose>
                    <v:when test="(i+j)%2==0"><td style="background: white;"></td></v:when>
                    <v:otherwise><td style="background: black;"></td></v:otherwise>
                </v:choose>                 
            </v:forEach></tr>
        </v:forEach>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas indicar que la expresión no es un literal, sino que debe ser procesada, usando la notación **`${...}`**:

```
<v:when test="${(i+j)%2==0}">
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ha sido una gran ayuda